# Separate HTTP connection results (PHP echo)

Tags: java, php, android

In my Android application I make a HTTP POST connection:

```
serverresponse = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(url, postParameters);
```

All working fine. The `url` is pointing to a php page on my server. It echos an array of image urls in JSON format like this:

`[".\/pictures\/q\/thumbnails\/28052011172.jpg",".\/pictures\/q\/thumbnails\/picca1.jpg",".\/pictures\/q\/thumbnails\/lockscreen_006.jpg"]`

What I want to do is also echo the size of directory. That works fine too, but that puts it right after the JSON array, like so:

```
echo (json_encode($files));
echo (filesize_r($path));
```

`[".\/pictures\/q\/thumbnails\/28052011172.jpg",".\/pictures\/q\/thumbnails\/picca1.jpg",".\/pictures\/q\/thumbnails\/lockscreen_006.jpg"]4223566`

4223566 is the number of bytes. In my application I want to split these two values into different strings so I can use them.

In short, I want to separate these two php echos. I don't want to make two separate HTTP connections for both of them.

Sorry if my question isn't clear enough, I sometimes have a hard time explaining stuff in English.

Comment: What do you mean by separate? You don't want second echo as response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not just make one json object which contains the two values your require?

e.g.

```
$response = array(
    'pictures'=>$files,
    'filesize'=> filesize_r($path)
);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: I was thinking about including the filesize inside the JSON object. Now I have to find out how to split them in my Android application. But I'll figure that out. This works so far. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use params in you php so you can select wich action to do

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I understand your question fully, but:

```
$json['files'] = $files;
$json['size'] = filesize_r($path);

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Indeed, same solution as Paul Brian. This works so far. Thanks as well.